# Using Hashtables to get random access to linked list

Tags: c++

One of major drawbacks to linked lists is that the access time to elements is linear. Hashtables, on the other hand, have access in constant time. However, linked lists have constant insertion and deletion time given an adjacent node in the list. I am trying to construct a FIFO datastructure with constant access time, and constant insertion/deletion time. I came up with the following code:

```
unordered_map<string key, T*> hashTable;
list<T> linkedList;
T Foo;
linkedList.push_front(Foo);
hashTable.insert(pair<string, T*>("A", &Foo);
T Bar;
linkedList.push_front(Bar);
hashTable.insert(pair<string, T*>("B", &Bar);
```

However, this code feels like it is really dangerous. The idea was that I could use the hashtable to access any given element in constant time, and since insertion always occurs at the start of the list, and deletion from the end of the list,  I can insert and delete elements in constant time. Is there anything inherently poor about the above code? If I wanted to instead store pointers to the nodes in the linkedList to have constant insertion/deletion time from any node would I just store list< T >::iterator*?

Comment: Your map doesn't contain pointers to elements of the list, but to local variables (what would presumably go out of scope and get destroyed soon, leaving the pointers dangling). As written, there's no connection at all between `hashTable` and `linkedList`

Comment: You may want to rethink `unordered_map`, since it's not guaranteed constant lookup (worst case is O(N)).

Comment: It's unclear how you plan to update `hashTable` when it comes time to remove from the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you build a lookup table you will end up with 2 data structures holding the same data which does not make any sense.

The best thing you can do is making your linked list ordered and build a sparse lookup table in some way to select the start node to search in order to amortize some run time.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear how you want to access the list elements. From the code you provided, I assume you want the first pushed node as "A", the second pushed node as "B", etc. Then my question is what happens when we delete the first pushed node? Does the second pushed node become "A"?

If the node identifiers don't change when updating the list, your approach seems alright.

If the node identifiers has to change on list update, then here is a lightweight and limited approach:

```
const int MAX_ELEMENTS = 3;

vector<int> arr(MAX_ELEMENTS + 1);
int head = 0, tail = 0;

int get_size() {
  if (head > tail)
    return tail + ((int)arr.size() - head);
  return tail - head;
}

void push(int value) {
  if (get_size() == MAX_ELEMENTS) {
    // TODO: handle push to full queue
    cout << "FULL QUEUE\n";
    return;
  }
  arr[tail++] = value;
  if (tail == (int)arr.size()) {
    tail = 0;
  }
}

int pop() {
  if (get_size() == 0) {
    // TODO: handle access to empty queue
    cout << "EMPTY QUEUE\n";
    return -1;
  }
  int result = arr[head++];
  if (head == (int)arr.size()) {
    head = 0;
  }
  return result;
}

int get_item_at(int id) {
  if (id >= get_size()) {
    // TODO: index out of range
    cout << "INDEX OUT OF RANGE\n";
    return -1;
  }
  int actual_id = head + id;
  if (actual_id >= (int)arr.size()) {
    actual_id -= (int)arr.size();
  }

  return arr[actual_id];
}
```

The above approach will keep indices up-to-date (eg. `get_item_at(0)` will always return the first node in the queue). You can map ids to any suitable id you want like "A" -> 0, "B" -> 1, etc. The limitation of this solution is that you won't be able to store more than `MAX_ELEMENTS` in the queue.

> If I wanted to instead store pointers to the nodes in the linkedList to have constant insertion/deletion time from any node would I just store list< T >::iterator*?

If identifiers must change with insertion/deletion, then it is going to take O(n) time anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This idea makes sense, especially for large lists where order of insertion matters but things might be removed in the middle.  What you want to do is create your own data structure:

```
template<typename T> class constantAccessLinkedList {
public:
void insert(const T& val) {
   mData.push_back(val); //insert into rear of list, O(1).
   mLookupTable.insert({val, mData.back()}); //insert iterator into map. O(1).
}

std::list<T>::iterator find(const T& val) {
   return mLookupTable[val]; //O(1) lookup time for list member.
}

void delete(const T& val) {
   auto iter = mLookupTable.find(val); //O(1)get list iterator
   mLookupTable.erase(val); //O(1)remove from LUT.
   mData.erase(iter); //O(1) erase from list.
}

private:
std::list<T> mData;
std::unordered_map<T, std::list<T>::iterator> mLookupTable;
};
```

The reason you can do this with list and unordered_map is because list::iterators are not invalidated on modifying the underlying container.

This will keep your data in order in the list, but will provide constant access time to iterators, and allow you to remove elements in constant time.